# Mathematical equation for pairing

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

There must be a mathematical answer for this…

We have a team of 10 people that needs to be divided into two teams, one made up of three, and a team of 7 for a two week duration.
After that two weeks, there should be a rotation, having three new people make up the team of three. The 3-person team will do the 'boring' work, so everyone needs to rotate through that, with the longest duration between stints.

I’d like the team of three to not be the same people every time, so everybody gets to work with everybody, so a brand new makeup every two weeks.

Later the teams will be 2 and 8 rather than 3 and 7 as we leverage automation to remove the toil

EDIT: Suggestion was to shuffle this by hand - I'll have a go at the below results, trick now will be to maximise the duration between stints!
[image: Groups]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Dan: AIUI, the OP wants a combinatorial design that uniformly traverses the $3$-element subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots,10\}$, ideally by a solution technique that constructs a design for the $2$-element subsets as well.

Comment: There are 120 teams of 3 (and 45 teams of 2). Generating the list of teams is straightforward. Rearranging the list to maximize the time between someone getting picked for the team again is slightly trickier. I guess you'd also like to maximize the time for a pair of people to be picked again for the team of 3.

Comment: Thank you for defining the question better @JacobManaker.

Comment: @PM2Ring, Indeed, because the 3-man team rotation is not a desirable team to be in, everyone would have to rotate through that team before having to join it again - good observation

Comment: As Jacob alluded to, this is a problem in [combinatorial design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_design), which is a rather large field. We can help you find solutions, but you need to make some kind of tangible attempt yourself. Otherwise, this question is likely to get closed &/or downvoted, and any answers will attract downvotes too.

Comment: A simple approach is to generate the ordered list of teams and the shuffle it. That won't maximize the time, but (I think) it will be a lot better than the ordered list.

Comment: I've managed to find the 120 combinations of the 3-person team (calculators.io), so worse case, we can shuffle those as suggested. 
This is an entirely new train of though, and had a crack at it in Excel, by trying to guess combinations. Math of this kind is not my strong suit! I understand your point though, I just don't think I'll up with anything proper in a reasonable timeframe. A shuffled list still achieves the same thing in the end, so will go with that as a workable option if needs must. Appreciate the answers, it placed me miles ahead from where I was an hour ago!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137801/discussion-between-pm-2ring-and-werner).